# How to save and update multiple rows

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to save some user settings in a database.
The settings are represented by checkboxes.

```
<td>
    {{$user->bitrixId}}<input type="hidden" name="bitrixId[]" value="{{$user->bitrixId}}">
</td> 

<input type="checkbox" class="input-group" name="commercial[]" Value="0"> 
<input type="checkbox" class="input-group" name="domestic[]" Value= "0">
```

The controller method which is supposed to store the settings:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $bitrixIds[] = $request->bitrixId;
    $commercial = [];
    $domestic = [];
    $agent_Type = new AgentTypes($request->all());

    foreach ($bitrixIds as $bt) {
        $ag = new AgentTypes();
        $ag->bitrixId = $bt;
        $ag->commercial = json_encode($agent_Type->commercial);
        $ag->domestic = json_encode($agent_Type->domestic);
        $ag->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have many item in blade with one name :

```
<input type="text" name="commercials[1][name]"  class="form-control m-input">


<input type="text" name="commercials[2][name]"  class="form-control m-input">

<input type="text" name="commercials[3][name]"  class="form-control m-input">


<input type="text" name="commercials[1][family]"  class="form-control m-input">
```

that you can define a variable for number `1 2 3` and `++` for each one .

now in your controller you can use this variable :

```
$commercials= $request->get("commercials");

 if (isset($commercials) && $commercials!= [])
        {
 foreach ($commercials $perCommercial)
            {
                commercialas::create([
                    "name"      => $perCommercial["name"],
                    "family"  => $perCommercial["family"]
                ]);
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this 
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $bitrixIds = $request->bitrixId;
    $commercial = $request->commercial;
    $domestic = $request->domestic;

    foreach ($bitrixIds as $key => $bt) {
        $ag = new AgentTypes();
        $ag->bitrixId = $bt;
        $ag->commercial = $commercial[$key];
        $ag->domestic = $domestic[$key];
        $ag->save();
    }
}
```